# Why can't my tax_a,b,c be found?

Tags: python

The purpose is to get the income from the user and apply a set of taxes based on the amount of money the user earns.

```
income = float(input('Enter your income:  $ '))

if income < 35000:
    tax_a = float((income * 0.15))

if (income - 35000) < 100000:
    tax_b = float((income * 0.25))

if (income - 100000) > 100000:
    tax_c = float((income * 0.35))

if income > 50000:
    tax_s = (income * 0.05)

fed_tax = float((tax_a + tax_b + tax_c))
total_tax = (fed_tax + tax_s)

print('Your total tax liability is:  ${:.2f}'.format(total_tax))
print('[details Federal tax: {:.2f}, State tax: {:.2f}'.format(fed_tax, tax_s))
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only defining `tax_a`, `tax_b`, `tax_c` and `tax_s` if some condition is true. If the condition is not true, you leave the variable undefined.

I'm not a tax lawyer, but I assume the tax in a given category is 0 if the condition does not apply:

```
if income < 35000:
    tax_a = float((income * 0.15))
else:
    tax_a = 0.0
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialize your variables and learn about "variable scope".

```
tax_a = tax_b = tax_c = tax_s = 0
income = float(input('Enter your income:  $ '))
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python incometax.py 
Enter your income:  $ 100000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "incometax.py", line 15, in <module>
    fed_tax = float((tax_a + tax_b + tax_c))
NameError: name 'tax_a' is not defined
```

The problem is that `tax_a` is only defined when a certain condition occurs. Since you always need these variables in the final calculation, you should define them at the beginning of your program:

```
tax_a = 0.0
```

p.s. Note that all of the `float()` calls are unnecessary if you initialize variables with floats to begin with and use floating point constants.